# Connect to OpenVPN server in Python 3 AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openvpn

I need to be able to connect to an OpenVPN server using a .ovpn file within a Python 3 script. Right now my script runs just fine, as the machine I'm running it on is connected to the OpenVPN server using Tunnelblick.

The goal is to have this run in an AWS Lambda function. So as part of the execution it would use the ovpn cert to connect the vpn, do it's thing, then disconnect.

Maybe I'm just looking for a module that functions as an OpenVPN Client?
I'm currently using the `paramiko` module to ssh into a Linux box also connected to the OpenVPN server.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(remote_ip, username='username', password=password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(diagnose_script)
stdin.flush()
data = stdout.read().splitlines()
results = ''
for line in data:
    results += line.decode('utf-8')
    results += '\n'
return results
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Aren't you using a wrong tool for the job in this case? Perhaps a more appropriate solution would be to use AWS VPC?

Comment: That did cross my mind, but I have potentially thousands of Linux boxes that I can have connect to the OpenVPN server over the internet. If I too am connected to the OpenVPN server(which is internet facing), I can then ssh into those boxes on the private OpenVPN subnet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hundreds/thousands of boxes to connect to - AWS VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) sounds like a proper solution for your problem. It might a bit more effort and cost, but it's sustainable in the long term and I would say more secure.

There are [multitude](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/network-to-amazon-vpc-connectivity-options.html) of options to choose from, and in your case [AWS Managed VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/aws-managed-vpn-network-to-amazon.html) or [Software VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/software-vpn-network-to-amazon.html) would fit best. Then you can have your Lambdas and outside AWS resources to run in one network.

Connecting to an OpenVPN from AWS Lambda is possible, you can install any packages you want, since it's a Linux container and I'm pretty sure there are some answers here about it, albeit it will cost you quite a bit of execution time especially if the function won't be called in a high volume (at least once per minute or so), since the container will have to start up and all the packages to be setup again.

Comment: AWS Managed VPN could work, but the infrastructure is already setup in such a way that it's using OpenVPN. Also, this function will only be run on demand, and it may go days without being invoked. Any suggestions on getting and OpenVPN Client setup and connected in the Lambda container?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use AWS Lambda?

Comment: The idea is it's easy to send a payload from almost any platform and get the returned information. Although it's sounding like it may be best to spin up a t2.micro which I could then easily connect to the OpenVPN Server, then figure out a way to invoke my Python script on that EC2 box. I'm open to other methods, but I need to be able to connect to the OpenVPN server one way or another to get on the same subnet as these remote boxes.

Comment: If you want to use AWS products - perhaps ECS would be a better solution? You could send a payload to Lambda, which could then run a task in an ECS container? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html